# Preferential ordering of content when comparing two items side by side

Tags: gui-design, layout, content, ordering

When comparing two items side by side, is it better to show the given or known item first or show the unknown variable first?

[image]
[image]

I have a tabbed interface to show the differences of common eye issues compared to a normal eye. The tabbed interface is a fixed UI parameter and in this context is intended for a user to browse various eye ailments to compare a graphic side by side with a normal eye.

The common eye content will be the same across each tab. In this setup, I'm assuming a user will perform a rollover action over multiple eye-disorders in a session.

Is it best to place the common eye graphic on the left or on the right?

Answer (score 1):

You could do either, depending on how you want to present the information. Do you want to emphasize "normal" or are you trying to emphasize the "non-normal" condition? Users will *tend* to scan from left-to-right - placing the object you want emphasize to the left would make sense as a result.

Because the "normal" condition is common across all tabs, you can also remove it from the tab's scope. You can organize the visuals in a way to further emphasize one condition over another. It also does not trick the user into thinking both graphics might be changing - the tabs clearly relate to just one graphic, not both.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZXnZi.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>